# sqlite: can a db-name, table-name, column-name be an expression?

Tags: sqlite, set

I want to fill a sql-table by update-function and choosing the columns in an expression like this:

```
update marks set (select name from students where id='1')='AAA'
where subject='math';
```

To explain it simply.
I'd like to use an expression for column-name in a trigger to create a relational table value by value using the SET operator.

```
table students:
id name
 1 Max
 2 Joe
 3 Jim

table marks:
subject Max  Joe  Jim
math    AAA  B    C
sport   NULL NULL A
```

In my case a phyton script fills the table 'temps' row by row with sensor readings, 'SensorID' and 'Timestamp'. The lookup table 'sensors' can tell the 'SensorName' according each 'SensorID'. Now a trigger shall automatically fill a pivot table 'T1Table' with a timestamp of zeroed seconds `substr(new.timestamp,1,17)||'00'`.

```
timestamp           T1   T2   T3
2015-01-01 12:35:00 23.5 22.3 NULL
```

The source code would look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_T1 AFTER INSERT ON temps
BEGIN
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO T1Table(TimeStamp) VALUES(substr(new.timestamp,1,17)||'00');
UPDATE T1Table SET (select sensorName from sensors where sensors.sensorID=new.sensorID)=
ROUND(new.temperature,1)
WHERE TimeStamp=substr(new.timestamp,1,17)||'00';
END;
```

unfortunately it doesn't work as I like, this is the error message

```
Error: near "(": syntax error
```

it seems the SET operator expects a hard coded entry. 
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Comment: You're having trouble formulating a solution because your `marks` table is not normalized. Frankly, it violates several principles of a *relational* database system just by having the values of the `students` table as column names. If instead you had a third table, `subjects`, your `marks` table would contains `student_id`, `subject_id`, `mark`. With this structure, you have no need for the dynamic column name. Applied to your real-life situation, your sensor-record table would like like: `sensor_id`, `trial_number`, `reading` (for example). Then you create your output with a PIVOT statement.

Comment: Hi Cory, the goal of the marks table is to be not normalized - to create the pivot with the help of a trigger, just after the normalized table is updated. The reason why I want to create the pivot directly and not via a VIEW statement is that with more than half a million data sets, the raspberrypi is too busy to make a pivot everytime I need a (gnu)plot.
By the way, what do you mean by PIVOT statement?

Comment: I'm not certain if SQLite has a `PIVOT` statement in its SQL language, but most others include a `PIVOT` statement that lets you write a query which does the row->column transformation for you. There are also way to pivot without using this statement, such as the `CASE` method in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919602/best-way-to-do-a-pivot-table-in-sqlite.